# Interpreting GARCH (1,1) model with external regressor in variance equation using rugarch

Tags: interpretation, garch, volatility

I run a standard GARCH (1,1) model and obtain the following results.

[image]

Thereafter, I add an external regressor in the same model and obtain the following results:

[image]

The GARCH coefficient (beta1) is zero and the p-value is 1. The coefficient of the external regressor (vxreg1) is 0.415 with p-value of 0.000.

I use the robust standard errors.

How to interpret the result? Should I concur that the external regressor reduces/removes volatility contemporaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. I would not say the external regressor *reduces/removes* volatility but it is able to *fit/explain* it better than the previous period's conditional variance $\sigma_{t-1}^2$ can. This reminds me a bit of the realized GARCH model. There, including lagged realized variance into the conditional variance equation tends to make the lagged squared return term not statistically significant; see slide 36 of Peter R. Hansen's ["Lecture 3: Realized GARCH Models"](https://econ.au.dk/fileadmin/site_files/filer_oekonomi/subsites/creates/Diverse_2016/PhD_High-Frequency/3RealizedGARCH.pdf) (2016). Meanwhile, in your case the external regressor does the same for lagged conditional variance.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JyotiNair, you are welcome! I am still thinking why/how this would be happening.

Comment: I ran a return equation of ARMA (6,3), as the optimised lags with minimum AIC score. If there is anyway I can share the data with you, and if you are keen, I will be more than happy to share.

Comment: @JyotiNair, thank you, but I am thinking more in theoretical terms here.

Comment: The returns are of commodity futures and the external regressor is the speculation ratio, as calculated by Garcia et al., (1986). Basically, the ratio is Volume/Open Interest on any given day. This is to understand if speculative activities affect the volatility of the returns.

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that the volatility is completely driven by the external regressor, which is the speculative activity?

Comment: @JyotiNair, well, you have a statistically significant $\alpha_1$, so past squared error has something to say about today's conditional variance, too, even when the external regressor is accounted for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation